# "Died to protect" vs "died protecting"

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference in meaning?

1- He **died to protect** his daughter.

2- He **died protecting** his daughter.

Comment: Is there any difference in meaning? Yes. I downvoted and voted to close because you provided no context, no research...

Comment: 1) he died in order to protect his daughter 
2) he died while he was protecting his daughter

Comment: OP could find some help from this post https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/131207

Answer (score 1):

1. This means that him dying directly cause the protection of his daughter. As a result of him dying, his daughter is protected.
2. This means that in the processing of trying to protect his daughter, he died. He may or may not have succeeded in protecting her(usually the implication would be that he did succeed). The dying was not a part of the protection, it just happened during the protection attempt.

Comment: Do you know why I restricted my answer to a ‘comment’?

Comment: @Void No I don't

Comment: Because the question, as posed, is awful and out of kilter with the site's ethos; that is to say, no context, no research (a cursory Google search) at all and doesn't deserve an answer. Sure our goal is to help people, but they should at least attempt to find an answer on their own.

Comment: Comments and votes on the original question can judge whether a question is valid. I was providing an answer so I put it as an answer.